# shmat returns segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

Im trying to write into shared memory but for some reason after i call shmat() and strcpy i get segmentation fault(core dumped) why is that?

This is my code:

```
int fd,shmid;
key_t shmkey;
char *shm_add;
pid_t pid,pid1=0,pid2=0;

shmkey=ftok("shmdemo.c",'j');
if ( shmkey == (key_t)-1 )
 {
    printf("main: ftok() for shm failed\n");
    return -1;
}
shmid=shmget(shmkey, 50, 0666 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL);
if (shmid == -1)
{
    printf("main: shmget() failed\n");
    return -1;
}
shm_add=(char *)shmat(shmid,0,0);
if ( shm_add==NULL )
{
    printf("main: shmat() failed\n");
    return -1;
 }

strcpy(shm_add,"hello");
```

edit: I have file name shmdemo.c on the directory, and the errno of shmget say "File exists" but when i delete "shmdemo.c" from the directory, a new errno comes in the ftok that say "No such file or directory".

Thank you, Asaf.

Comment: What's the value of `shm_add`? (Or, generally, check the return values of all the syscalls if they report success.)

Comment: Ok i added return for the syscalls, the problem is on shmget. why?

Comment: Well, what's [the value of `errno` after the call fails](http://linux.die.net/man/3/perror)? And, consequently, what does [`man shmget`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmget) say the errno value means?

Comment: OK, so the errno of shmget say "file exist" but - when i delete shmdemo.c from the directory, there is new error in ftok that say "No such file or directory"

Comment: `EEXIST` doesn't mean the file used for the key exists, it means a shared memory segment for that key already exists. (`shmget` doesn't operate on files...) IIRC, shared memory segments stay around after the program exits/crashes if you don't clean them up, so if you've opened one while poking around at the program, it's still there.

Comment: You might like to use `ipcrm`  from the command line to remove shared memory segemts.

Comment: Use uh... [`ipcs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ipcs) and [`ipcrm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ipcrm) to clean them up. (I'm on Windows right now and am mostly going off memory of that same class.) Also maybe try `atexit()` to make sure they get cleaned up even if something goes wrong - although it won't help in case of a crash.

Comment: Ok i get it, there is a way to remove the shared memory from my progrem and not from the command line before i create new one?

Comment: @asafregev There probably is! In fact I'd bet it's one of the functions mentioned in the "See Also" section of the multiple man pages I already linked you to, whose name likely starts with `shm`.

Comment: Use `shmtcl()` with `IPC_RMID` to remove the shared memory segment.  Always make sure you know what is going to release/destroy any resources you acquire.  Often, program termination will do that; in the case of shared memory and message queues and semaphore sets, they exist across program invocations, so you have to clean up explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Answerifying the various comments. When you call:

```
shmget(..., IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL);
```

what you're saying with the flags is: Create a *new* shared memory segment for this key, **and** make sure no shared memory segment exists with that key already.

If you only use:

```
shmget(..., IPC_CREAT);
```

you're saying: If a shared memory segment *already exists* with this key, return it; **otherwise** create a new one for this key and return that.

Generally, you probably don't want the second variant of the call. Concurrency is hard enough without adding any nondeterminism of your own. (I.e. just letting whichever of a bunch of cooperating processes comes first create the shared memory; as opposed to having a designated "owner" process.)

When using the first call, if a shared memory segment already exists at the given key, the syscall fails with the `errno` value `EEXISTS`. SysV IPC are persistent, so they don't get automatically cleaned up after your program exits like, say, file descriptors. (In fact, they're more analogous to temporary files.)

You should clean them up in your program using something like [`shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmctl). You can also check for stray IPC objects using [`ipcs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ipcs) and remove the ones left behind with [`ipcrm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ipcrm) or [`cleanipcs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cleanipcs).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `IPC_EXCL` flag and check the program.

Comment: Well when i remove this it's work! What is the importance of this? i still have to delete the segment before create a new one?

Comment: @asafregev Without `IPC_EXCL` you'll get the previously created shared memory segment if one is there. Do note however that it will have the size it was first allocated with, not the one in the current `shmget` call, which is why you use `IPC_EXCL` when you want to be sure you're getting a new memory segment. (Which is usually the expectation when you don't want to fetch a previously created one explicitly.)

Comment: Using IPC_EXCL means you are guaranteed that no other process is using the shared memory key; if you don't use that in the `shmget()` call, you might be using someone else's chunk of shared memory, which is usually a cause of great unhappiness to at least one of the programs.  So, the IPC_EXCL parameter is important for safety in the long run.  In the short term, omitting IPC_EXCL would get the code past the hump until you sort out deleting the shared memory segment before the program exits.

Comment: @asafregev Or, to rephrase things: you probably **don't want to not use** `IPC_EXCL`. Here, using the flag wasn't the *cause* of your problem, it's what made it *manifest*. In effect, it helped you catch a bug - shared memory not being created by the process you think is creating it - instead of having your program silently do what's potentially the wrong thing. It probably doesn't matter in homework, but generally when dealing with concurrency, you want shared resources to be accessed in precisely the way you expect them to be accessed. (In fact, that's the whole point of synchronization.)

Comment: (Hence also my -1. This answer suggests a hackish, potentially dangerous workaround instead of getting at the root of the issue.)